# Using google calender Api v3 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

I’m stuck at the authorization of the Google Calendar Api version3

What I’m trying to build is an application that feeds content of a database to the Google calendar

I got this application fully working under Google Api version 2. 
However there are some new features in version 3 i want to use.

unfortunately version 3 is backwards incompatible

this is my code so far:

```
Imports DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2

Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Util

Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())

    Dim provider = New NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
    provider.ClientIdentifier = "<client id>"
    provider.ClientSecret = "<client secret>"
    Dim auth = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, AddressOf GetAuthorization)

    Dim service = New CalendarService(auth)

End Sub

Private Shared Function GetAuthorization(arg As NativeApplicationClient) As IAuthorizationState

    Dim scopes As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)

    scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue())

    Dim state As IAuthorizationState = New AuthorizationState(scopes)
    state.Callback = New Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl)
    Dim authUri As Uri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state)

    Process.Start(authUri.ToString())

    Return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(state)

End Function
```

I get an error; 
Error1'IAuthorizationState' is ambiguous in the namespace 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2'.

I don't know what I’m doing wrong ( i follow every step of the Google api manual, also have al the DLL needed)

Hopefully some one can help me.

Thanks in advance for your effort! :)

Comment: The error is telling you that there are two types both called `IAuthorizationState`.  If you need to import the namespaces for both of those types (which it sounds like you're doing) then you'll need to fully-qualify that type name.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your quick reply. I cannot find the other DLL that contains `IAuthorizationState` except `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2`

Comment: Interesting.  Is that library somehow being loaded twice during compilation?  Maybe there's an error in the project file?  What happens if you remove the `Imports` directive for `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2` (and fully-qualify anything that uses it)?

Comment: Strange if i outcomment `'import DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2 ` and then type `'Private Shared Function GetAuthorization(arg As NativeApplicationClient) As DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState '` the DLL doesn't recornize the command.

Comment: Fixed the issue, i imported the DLL via NuGet, it seems dat it installed `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2 and DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.client` However the last compile error i got is : `'Error 1 Value of type 'Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator(Of Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.NativeApplicationClient)' cannot be converted to 'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer'.` I'm guessing i'm using an wrong DLL however i got is from the google website and cannot find a other newer version of it.

Comment: Glad it was an easy fix.  For completeness, you can even add that as an answer to your own question so that anybody who faces a similar issue might be helped as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, i imported the DLL via NuGet, it seems dat it installed `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2` and `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.client`

However, i didn't manage to get Google Calender Api v3 working and so made the app in Api v2, works like a charm! :)

Still i found it odd of google that v3 with the OAuth2 isn't working correctly for VB.Net